# Best way to Programatically write HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

What would be the best way to go about programatically writing many lines of HTML in the following format:

```
<div class="grid-item"> <img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" alt="image-GLITCH"/> </div>
<div class="grid-item"> <img src="gifs/image.gif" 
alt="image"/> </div>
<div class="grid-item"> <img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" 
alt="image-GLITCH"/> </div>
```

The end result is a grid of gifs where the center column contains a normal image, while the left and right columns contain "GLITCH" versions of the image.

Desired end result: many many rows of the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG08z.jpg

I've thought about using php like:

```
$images = glob("gifs/*.gif}");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo <div class="grid-item"> <img src=$image alt=""/> </div>
}
```

Please note that the above is not the exact php I would use, I don't know how to exclude search strings with glob (I believe you can't do that). But this question is meant to ask:

"What is the best way to programatically write html in order to create a grid of images like that contained in the attached image." [i.e this question is not about the actual code to write, but instead what method of writing code should be used: javascript? php?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about this would definitely be with PHP (or a different server-side language). And for that matter, you can completely take **[`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)** out of the equation; you don't want to output based on how many images you have, you want to output a fixed number of images so that it *results* in the pattern you desire.

First, let's take a look at your raw HTML:

```html
<div class="grid-item">
  <img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" alt="image-GLITCH" />
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <img src="gifs/image.gif" alt="image" />
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" alt="image-GLITCH" />
</div>
```

Every second row alternates. The only difference is the `<img>` `src` and `alt`.

Now let's say you have a total of `33` of these (start with a glitch and ending with a glitch), giving a 'nice' number. That's really easy to set up in a PHP loop, using **[modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)**. All you need to do is check whether the variable in your loop divided by your desired 'glitch insertion' offset (every second image in my example) has a remainder or not:

```
<?php

$image_count = 33;
for ($i = 0; $i < $image_count; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="grid-item"><img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" alt="image-GLITCH"/></div>' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo '<div class="grid-item"><img src="gifs/image.gif" alt="image"/></div>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Now you have all of the images outputted correctly, just as with the HTML snippet above.

Also, don't forget your quotation marks around your string!

This can be seen working [**here**](https://3v4l.org/75o5U):

```
<div class="grid-item"><img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" alt="image-GLITCH"/></div>
<div class="grid-item"><img src="gifs/image.gif" alt="image"/></div>
<div class="grid-item"><img src="gifs/image-GLITCH.gif" alt="image-GLITCH"/></div>
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would a server-side language be better than a client-side language for this?

Comment: Well for starters it gives you knowledge of the files on the server (if you're going to do something programmatic with them like `glob()` or use their name), and it also separates logic from presentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after a javascript solution for this?

```
(function($) {
    var imageUrl = "gifs/image.gif";

    var markup = glitichify(imageUrl);

    $(markup).appendTo($elementToAppendThisTo);

    function glitichify(imageUrl) {
        var imageUrlParts = imageUrl.split(".");
        var glitchImageUrl = imageUrlParts[0] + "-GLITCH" + imageUrlParts[1];
        var imageUrls = [glitchImageUrl, imageUrl, glitchImageUrl];

        var imageMarkup = imageUrls.map(function(imageUrl, index) {
            return '<div class="grid-item"> <img src="' + imageUrl + '" alt="image"/> </div>';
        });

        return imageMarkup.join("");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use an UI framework like [React](https://reactjs.org/) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) and no html engine like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) to generate img tags out of a loop you could do it with js. At least the place where you get your images counts. If you want to include your images dynamically from your local folder you should write a server side script to get an array of your images and then you could pass it to js or use it with your server side lang like php.

```js
var data = ['https://picsum.photos/300?random', 'https://picsum.photos/300?random', 'https://picsum.photos/300?random'],
    section = document.querySelector('section');

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = data[i];
  section.appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```